# Simple PHP if statement doesn't work

Tags: php, if-statement

I need a simple php if statement that checks if anything is assigned to a variable. If the variable is empty I don't want anything to display but if is there is something assigned to the variable I would like a line of html to be displayed.

Right now, the html is displayed whether the variable is assigned a value or not. Here is the if statement:

```
if(!isset($twitter)) {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '<li><a href="http://twitter.com/' . $twitter . '"><span class="ss-twitter ss-icon" style="background-color:' . $iconbgcolor . '; color:' . $iconcolor . '">L</span></a>';
    }
```

If you want to see the rest of the code for the project is found [here](https://github.com/ThisIsDallas/WP-Simple-Social/blob/master/wp-simple-social.php).

I have also tried using the empty function but that wouldn't work either.

Comment: Check line 175 of your code, it's either assigned &nbsp; or $instance['twitter'] which makes this a set variable and will always return true on !isset($twitter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['twitter'];
```

Variable is always exists
Try:

```
 $twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '' : $instance['twitter']; 

if(!empty($twitter)) {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '<li><a href="http://twitter.com/' . $twitter . '"><span class="ss-twitter ss-icon" style="background-color:' . $iconbgcolor . '; color:' . $iconcolor . '">L</span></a>';
    }
```

Comment: I have to wait five min to accept your answer but I will as soon as I am able to.

Comment: There should not be a  `!` in `if(!empty($twitter)) {`

Answer (score 3):

You set the `$twitter` as below:

```
$twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['twitter'];
```

So `$twitter` is always set and won't be empty. `'&nbsp;'` is not an empty string.

Use `null` instead.

```
$twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? null  : $instance['twitter'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this line is your problem:

```
$twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['twitter'];
```

So `$twitter` will be set regardless of the index `'twitter'` in the `$instance` array being empty or not. If empty: `'&nbsp;'`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a little puzzling:

On line 175 it does this:

```
$twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['twitter'];
```

Which sets it to either the `$instance['twitter']` or ' ' - neither of which are null.

and the on 201 in the same function:

```
if(!isset($twitter))
```

Which means that `$twitter` will be set no matter what. If it was empty on 175, it now contains `&nbsp;` which means it *is* set.

I would suggest changing line 175 to:

```
$twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '' : $instance['twitter'];
```

and line 201 to:

```
if(empty($twitter))
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `if(empty($twitter))` with your code?

Comment: @xdazz Yes, and answer is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your line

```
$twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '&nbsp;' : $instance['twitter'];
```

to

```
$twitter = empty( $instance['twitter'] ) ? '' : $instance['twitter'];
```

After that, your `if` condition will work.

Cheers.